# How to run a MATLAB program for a specified time duration?

Tags: matlab

For example if there is a MATLAB program as follows:

```
duration = 1 % minute
i=1
while i<1000
   [X,Y] = ginput(1)
i = i+1;
end
```

Is there any way to terminate the execution of this program or getting out of the loop when it reaches to the assigned amount of time (1 minute in this case) in such a situation in which continuation of the loop needs the user intervention (in this case clicking on any point on the plotted figure)?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do. Calling `ginput` will wait indefinitely until the user clicks. Do you want to interrupt `input` so if a user takes too long it will give up and either continue running other code or throw an error?

Comment: @horchler yes, the reason I put {ginput} is that I wanted to emphasize on the termination of the execution of the loop even if it is waiting for inputs from the user or the loop has not finished at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a process within your loop for a minimum of a minute, you can do it like this:

```
start = now
while now - start < 60/60/24
    %do something for a minute
end
```

As a commenter above said, ginput will wait indefinitely so don't plan on that working.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But it cannot terminate the loop when it is still within the loop at the ending time for cases like that I have mentioned before.